# Merge subtitle of two figures Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to add to my overleaf document two groups of two figures (the first two for France, the second two for Italy) that share a caption below. However, everything I tried either only keeps the first caption as the title for all the figures or does not encompass the two charts. How can I create a caption that only affects the two previous figures?

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,name=FIGURE,font=custom}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,font=custom,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{France charts}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Italy charts}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: I just added all packages. I am not sure if I can also upload the graphs myself or not.

Comment: No need to upload the graphs, you could use a dummy image like `example-image` which should be included in most tex distributions for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Did you test the code? It does not compile because of missing packages/unknown options.

Comment: for me it works well, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: This can't work for you. You can't use the `[H]` floating specifier if you don't load the float package. `font=custom` is also fishy ....

Comment: If I copy paste the code above it does work. I edited the question with a screenshot of what I get. The idea would be to have the captions in the middle so they apply to both images.

Comment: See the red square at the top right of https://www.overleaf.com/read/ywwgfpqqvrwx  ?-> this tells you that there are 4 errors in the code. If there are errors, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major errors in the code:

1. If you want to use the `[H]` floating specifier, you must load the `float` package
2. `font=custom` will produce errors

---

You can use `\captionsetup{justification=centering}` to switch back to centred captions for your figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,name=FIGURE}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{France charts}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Italy charts}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]